# Creating meteor autoform w/ array of radio buttons

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'd like to build an autoform in meteor that presents user with a twelve radio buttons and records an entry for each of the 12 buttons. I can get the form working easily enough if I create 12 different buttons—see below, but I'm wondering if it is possible to create an array to do this a bit more easily.

```
Homework = new Mongo.Collection("homework");
Homework.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
userId:{
    type: String,
    autoValue:function(){return this.userId},

},
userName:{
    type: String,
    autoValue:function(){return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).emails[0].address},
},
fName:{
    type: String,
    autoValue:function(){return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).profile.fName},
},
lName:{
    type: String,
    autoValue:function(){return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).profile.lName},
},

page: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Page Number",
    max: 200
},
problem1: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem2: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem3: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem4: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem5: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem6: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem7: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem8: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem9: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem10: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem11: {
    type: Boolean,
},
problem12: {
    type: Boolean,
},

}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup! You can simple define arrays in SimpleSchema using this notation:

```
...

  'problems': {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        options: function () { return {
          one: 'one',
          two: 'two',
          three: 'three',
          four: 'four',
          five: 'five',
          six: 'six',
        } }
      }
    }
  }

...
```

And in your template

```
{{ > afQuickField name="problems" noselect=true }}
```

Comment: Hmm. That seems to produce a field that lets me select one of 6 different options, which isn't quite what I want. I want want to see n separate boolean checkboxes, one for each of the n problems. Is that possible?

Comment: Ahh, I see—the noselect=true modifier turns the multiple select into a series of radio buttons.

Comment: How would I call this field from a {{quickform}} template? the noselect attribute seems to be ignored in this case.

Comment: Well you'll have to use an `autoForm`-block and and [`afQuickFields`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#afquickfields) for the other fields

Comment: All of these radio buttons are linked—I can only select one of the items. Is there a way to configure this so that they act like checkboxes and I can select multiple items?

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry I thought you wanted that. In that chase you'll just need to remove the `noselect=true`.

Comment: That changes it into a select box where you can choose one of the many options. What I would like to see is a series of n checkboxes, where you can check any number of the boxes independently.

Comment: Well then you can't use an array. You'll have to use an object. `{{ > afObjectField name="problems" }}`

`problems: {
    type: Object
  },

  'problems.one': {
    type: Boolean
  },

  'problems.two': {
    type: Boolean
  },[...]`

Comment: Can you then iterate over all of the booleans in the problems object?

Comment: I'd use underscores [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each). You could also use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) or a simple [`for in`-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement).

Comment: Can you link me to a bit more of an explanation on how to iterate over all of the elements in problems?

Comment: First you have to retrieve docs [`find`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find). This returns you a [`cursor`](docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_cursor). It has a function called [`forEach`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/foreach). Inside the `forEach` callback you now have the whole document. The document is a normal [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) with the same properties as the document. So now, let's say you called the first arg `doc`. Then you can do `_.each(doc.problems, function (problem) {...})`.